# Considerar rotas de ida e volta de maneira idêntica

Tags: r

Estou com dificuldade para codificar a variável `rota` no R para que ela assuma um valor único quando a rota for a mesma, independente do ponto de origem (primeiros 4 caracteres da variável rota) e de destino (últimos 4 caracteres). A base está da seguinte maneira:

```
    base <- data.frame(rota = c("SBAA - SBEE", "SBAA - SBBR", "SBAA - SBCI",
                                "SBEE - SBAA", "SBEE - SBBR", "SBBR - SBEE"),
                       assentos = c(1231, 1021, 715, 989, 759, 695))

    base$rota<-as.character(base$rota)

  rota        assentos
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 SBAA - SBBE     1231
2 SBAA - SBBR     1021
3 SBAA - SBCI      715
4 SBEE - SBAA      989
5 SBEE - SBBR      759
6 SBBR - SBEE      695
```

Pensei em fazer uma transformação para gerar a variável `codigo`:

```
codigo<-as.numeric(as.factor(rota))
```

Entretanto, o output será diferente para rotas iguais (mesmos aeroportos se conectando), mas que tenham aeroporto de origem e destino invertidos. Por exemplo, "SBAA - SBBE" e SBBE - SBAA" deveriam ter o mesmo código,  mas ficarão da seguinte maneira:

```
  rota        assentos        codigo
  <chr>           <dbl>       <dbl>
1 SBAA - SBEE     1231         1
2 SBAA - SBBR     1021         2
3 SBAA - SBCI      715         3
4 SBEE - SBAA      989         4
5 SBEE - SBBR      759         5
6 SBBR - SBEE      695         6
```

Preciso que as rotas que tenham os mesmos aeroportos se conectando tenham o mesmo código de forma que a variável "codigo" retorne o seguinte resultado:

```
  rota        assentos        codigo
  <chr>           <dbl>       <dbl>
1 SBAA - SBEE     1231         1
2 SBAA - SBBR     1021         2
3 SBAA - SBCI      715         3
4 SBEE - SBAA      989         1
5 SBEE - SBBR      759         4
6 SBBR - SBEE      695         4
```

Repare que o código para "SBAA - SBEE" é idêntico ao "SBEE - SBAA".

---

**Solução**

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
base %>% 
    mutate(codigo = as.integer(factor(map_chr(str_extract_all(rota, 
          "\\w+"), ~ str_c(sort(.x), collapse=" - ")))))
```

Comment: `base[["rota"]] <- as.character(base[["rota"]])`


`base[["rota_unica"]] <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(base[["rota"]], " - "), function(x){
  x <- sort(x, method="radix")
  paste0(x, collapse= " - ")
}))`